# ngFor nested object list

Tags: javascript, angular5, ngfor

I have a list of nested objects and am using `ngFor` to iterate. But when I want to reach some child object's property I have to write chain of all properties from root object.I am trying to define additional variable and assign child object to it. Basically what I want to do is something like below but it gives error, I believe this is not right syntax

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of objs; let child = obj.childObject">
    <span>{{ child.name }}</span>
<div/>
```

How can I achieve to do this?

Comment: that is not supported in *ngFor in angular

Comment: I know but I want any alternative to do this

Comment: you can do like this `<div *ngFor="let obj of objs;">
    <span>{{ GetName(obj) }}</span>
<div/>` this function will return name or creating properly can also helps you

Comment: did you tried ng container?

Comment: @Pranay it's not that important as to create function for. I just wanted to know maybe there is easy way to do. Neenu no I haven't tried.

Comment: you are asking which is not present in framework

Comment: Well right then, it means there is no easy way to do this. I got it.

Comment: just try ng container , its an angular structural directive.

Answer (score 0):

Why not traversing the object chain inside the `span`:

```
<span *ngFor="let obj of objs">{{ obj.childObject.name }}</span>
```

EDIT after reading the comment. The above is for displaying a specific `childobject` property.

If the objective is to print all of `childobject`'s properties, then define `objectKeys` variable in component's class:

```
export class MyComponent {
  objectKeys = Object.keys;
  ...
}
```

Then provide the collection for which to iterate key as parameter to `objectKeys` in component's html:

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of objs">
    <span *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(obj.childobject)">{{key + ' : ' + obj.childobject[key]}}</span>
<div/>
```

Comment: @Hikmat you mean `obj.childObject` is sometimes undefined?

Comment: It goes messy if you have many children objects and their properties, you have to write same things a few times

Comment: No I mean if childObject has 5 properties I have to write obj.childObject 5 times. I don't wanna do it.

Comment: ngFor with `in`? it's not suported.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of objs;">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let child of obj.childObject;>
    <span>{{ child.name }}</span>
  </ng-container>
<div/>
```

Answer (score 0):

check my example, it's work

```
 <div *ngFor="let catergory of Catergories;">
      <span>{{ catergory.name }}</span>
      <div *ngFor="let product of catergory.products;>
        <span>{{ product.name }}</span>
      </div>
 <div/>
```